# Fullcite with Optex bibliography system

Tags: bibliographies, optex

I've been searching in the documentation, but haven't found a way to print, in the text, the complete reference of an entry. It would work just like the `\fullcite` command from Biblatex, which prints the entry in the text itself:

`\fullcite[olsak]` = Olšák, Petr. OpTEX – A new generation of Plain TEX. *TUGboat*. TEX Users Group, 2020, Vol. 41, No. 3, pp. 348–354.

In other words, when one calls it in the text it prints the full reference. I find it useful for syllabi. (It works somewhat like the [verbose style](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/70-style-verbose-bibtex.pdf) in biblatex.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what `\fullcite` in LaTeX does. Please, give a link to a clear example with explanation. Then I can start to think about it in OpTeX.

Comment: @wipet, sorry, I rephrased my question. See if it's clear now.

Comment: Yes, i is clear. It won't be done right away, I started to experiment with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created a new [OpTeX trick 0092](http://petr.olsak.net/optex/optex-tricks.html#fullcite) which implements `\fullcite`. You have to read the data from `.bib` file first at beginning of your document using

```
\readbib (simple) op-biblist
```

and then `\fullcite[label]` expands to the bibliographic record. It is far from ideal because bib system in OpTeX was borrowed completely from old OPmac and there is dependency on `librarian` package with not fully expandable macros. The plan is to rewritten this part of OpTeX in order to leave the `librarian` dependency and use Lua code for reading `.bib` files. But this is only plan, not realized in coming weeks.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. Much appreciated!